# When should I paginate my REST API response?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, laravel-5.1, amazon-elb

I'm currently having an issue with my production deployment setup on AWS.
I have an EC2 instance hosting NGINX/PHP/Laravel 5.1, that sits behind an AWS ELB.
One of my RESTAPIs returns a response that amounts to 1.2 to 1.6 MB, in a specific scenario (In most general scenarios, its returns much smaller response sizes), and the calls times-out.
The following error message gets logged

> upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response
>   header from upstream, client: xxxxxxxxxxx, server: xxxxxxxxxxx,
>   request: "POST /api/event/gallery HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "xxxxxxxxxxx"

1.2-1.6mb does not appear to be a large amount of response size to explain the timeout.

I did confirm that my actual PHP call (at the bottom of the call stack) returns within 20 seconds.

Subsequent investigations revealed that the AWS ELB has a timeout of 60 sec, and probably closes the connection.

> https://www.cadence-labs.com/2017/07/fix-nginx-timeout-499-client-closed-request/

My AWS EC2 instance is of type m4.large. And Im concerned about why a production setup with proven components like AWS ELB, NGINX, will have trouble handling 1.x mb of data efficiently. Its likely that Im doing something wrong, or I have not configured the overall deployment system correctly. Please help with your suggestions.

Or perhaps I'm being too optimistic, and should move to a paginate my response to cater to large response sizes. But then again, I don't want to paginate without understanding the limits, or clearly knowing when I should. What is the max size/limit for a REST API response, beyond which I should consider pagination?

Comment: There are can be many factors. 1) Either your database is not indexed properly. 2) Or its processing too many records in-memory. I would suggest you to load data using ->paginate() and fetch only necessary columns (not all).

Comment: I concur, the issue is not size, the issue is that your performance isn't good enough. Where is the bottleneck? Figure that out and measure.

Comment: @rahulb, the database is fine. Im ok with performance of < 20 sec in loading the data (its usually ~10 sec). Beyond that point, as the payload passes through nginx and elb, it take an additional 60sec plus.

Comment: @Evert, thank you for your suggestion. I intend to trace the payload and logs across php server, nginx and aws elb to figure out where the problem lies. Its likely that I have to change/set some configuration parameters.

Comment: While that's possible, it's also possible that your actual code is just slow.

Comment: @Evert, I alway wish for the problem to lie in my code. That way the solution is in my hands, and can fix, or update the solution to meet the expectations. Ill let you know about what I find out!